# mongodb error connecting to db "MongooseServerSelectionError"

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

what happens is that I have a JavaScript project which connects to MongoDB through mongoose, but when starting the server it gives me an error, and I already tried to add my IP manually on the MongoDB page, I also reset my firewall eh I even changed my router internet for my mobile and nothing works

The error is the following:

MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbnJG.png). One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting your IP manually, try once adding `0.0.0.0/0`. Is this solves your error then IP you are entering manually is wrong.

Comment: I already tried with access to my ip and also with access 0.0.0.0/0 and it doesn't work